# Check column type if it exists

Tags: r

I'm trying to create a validation stage for dataframes. I'm trying to use the validate library and have added elements as described in the documentation [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/validate/vignettes/cookbook.html#1_Introduction_to_validate).

I can't however see the right way to check a property of a column only when that column exists.

Following the cars example from the tutorial:

```
library(validate)
data(cars)
rules <- validator(speed >= 0, dist >= 0)
confront(cars, rules)
```

So that works fine. What I would like to do is add a rule so that if there is a name column to the car's data it will be of type character. However, when adding the rule as in the following, it raises an error because the names column doesn't exist for the rule can be run.

```
library(validate)
data(cars)
rules <- validator(speed >= 0, dist >= 0, is.character(name))
confront(cars, rules)
```

**update
I don't know if the following attempt better represents what I'm aiming for. This fails on syntax.

```
 rules <- validator(speed >= 0, dist >= 0, speed/dist <= 1.5, cor(speed, dist)>=0.2, ifelse(exists("name"), is.character(name),T))
```

Comment: Do you want to add a rule for a column that doesn't exist?

Comment: I want to add a rule for a column that may or may not exist. 
I know it doesn't exist in the cars data but I want to validate an equivalent cars data that does also have a name column. I want to do so with the same validation

Comment: Code works fine for me,  `Rules confronted: 3
   With fails   : 0
   With missings: 0
   Threw warning: 0
   Threw error  : 1` What output do you expect?

Comment: I don't want the error to be thrown by the lack of a names
Threw error  : 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Comparisons**
*All basic comparisons, including >,>=,==,!=,<=,<, %in% are validating statements. When executing a validating statement, the %in% operator is replaced with %vin%.*

**Logical operations**
*Unary logical operators ‘!’, all() and any define validating statements. Binary logical operations
including &,&&,|,||, are validating when P and Q in e.g. P & Q are validating. (note that the shortcircuits && and & onnly return the first logical value, in cases where for P && Q, P and/or Q are
vectors. Binary logical implication P ⇒ Q (P implies Q) is implemented as if ( P ) Q. The latter is interpreted as !(P) | Q.*

Also note that the dot in `names(.)` refers to data.frame you `confront`

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/validate/validate.pdf

```
rules <- validator(
  speed >= 0,
  dist >= 0,
  if("names" %in% names(.)) is.character(names),
  if("speed" %in% names(.)) is.character(speed),
  if("speed" %in% names(.)) is.numeric(speed)
)

results <- confront(cars, rules)

summary(results)

  name items passes fails nNA error warning                                        expression
1   V1    50     50     0   0 FALSE   FALSE                        (speed - 0) >= -0.00000001
2   V2    50     50     0   0 FALSE   FALSE                         (dist - 0) >= -0.00000001
3   V3     1      1     0   0 FALSE   FALSE !("names" %vin% names(.)) | (is.character(names))
4   V4     1      0     1   0 FALSE   FALSE !("speed" %vin% names(.)) | (is.character(speed))
5   V5     1      1     0   0 FALSE   FALSE   !("speed" %vin% names(.)) | (is.numeric(speed))
```